# javafx drag-and-drop moving icon

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx-2

I am working with drag and drop on JavaFX2. It's possible that the dragged-Object (maybe clone of the dragged object) following the mousecursor like on the JavaFX Scene Builder.

*This is my sample sourcecode:*

```
Pane pane;
private void dragAndDropExample() {
    pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPrefSize(800, 600);
    TitledPane titlePane = new TitledPane("Partial Order", pane);
    add(titlePane, 0, 2);

    pane.getChildren().add(createCircle(350, 300, Color.RED));
    pane.getChildren().add(createCircle(250, 300, Color.BROWN));

    pane.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) { 
            if (circleToMove != null) { 
                circleToMove.setCenterX(event.getX());
                circleToMove.setCenterY(event.getY()); 
            }

        }
    });
}

Circle circleToMove;

private Circle createCircle(double x, double y, Color color) {
    final Circle c = new Circle(x, y, 25);
    c.setFill(color);

    c.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("SetOnDragDetected");
            c.setFill(Paint.valueOf("blue"));
            Dragboard db = c.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString("foo " + c.hashCode());
            db.setContent(content);
            arg0.consume();
            circleToMove = c;
        }
    });

    c.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
        }
    });

    c.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Mouse Released");
            circleToMove = null;
        }
    });

    c.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            System.out.println("SetOnDragExited");
            System.out.println(event.getGestureSource());

        }
    });

    c.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            System.out.println("setOnDragOver " + c.hashCode());
            c.setFill(Paint.valueOf("white"));
            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    c.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("setOnDragDropped");
            c.setFill(Paint.valueOf("black"));

            if (arg0.getGestureSource() instanceof Circle) {

                if (arg0.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    System.out.println(c.hashCode() + " hat jetzt " + arg0.getDragboard().getString());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    c.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("setOnDragEntered");

        }
    });

    return c;
}
```

I tried with the mouseEvent on the pane, but this event does not get fired during drag and drop.

Answer (score 4):

You are using wrong handlers. There drag events are used to drag items between panes. If you want to just move handled object use next code:

```
private Circle createCircle(double x, double y, Color color) {
    final Circle c = new Circle(x, y, 25);
    c.setFill(color);

    c.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            c.relocate(event.getSceneX() - c.getRadius(), event.getSceneY() - c.getRadius());
        }
    });

    return c;
}
```

Also you can try to look at next subsample in the [Ensemble demo:](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.1/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Scenegraph/Events/Mouse%20Events)

Comment: I would like to drag and drop the circle into one other. If i only using the onMouseDragged, how i should implement the drop functionality?? Im a little bit confused!!!

Comment: @SergeyGrinev how is it possible to move shapes between Panes? I have found how to move object inside one pane, using MouseDragged, and I know how to drag and drop text between panes using DragDetected with clipboard, but I cant figure how to combine these two, to drag n drop Shapes that remain visible during process.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev  "StackOverflow doesn't understand links with spaces" in that case you can use the oracle link like this  http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.1/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Scenegraph/Events/Mouse+Events

Comment: @LalithJayasinghe but "+" escaped links do not work with Ensemble :)